# Fiberwise criterion for a stack to be a gerbe

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks, gerbes

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic stacks.

If the **geometric** fibres of $f$ are algebraic spaces, then $f$ is representable by algebraic spaces.

I'm wondering about analogues of this fiberwise criterion in the context of gerbes and DM stacks.

For instance:

Q1. If the **geometric** fibres of $f$ are DM stacks, then is $f$ representable by DM stacks?

Q2. If there is a finite (abstract) group $G$ such that the **geometric** fibres of $f$ are $G$-gerbes, then is $f$ a $G$-gerbe?

Comment: The answer to Q1 should be positive, as checking whether a morphism of algebraic spaces is (formally) unramified can be done on geometric points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for **Q2**, I don't think so. For example, consider $(BG \times (\mathbb{A}^1\setminus \{ 0 \}))\amalg BG\to \mathbb{A}^1$, everything over $\mathbb{C}$.

**Added** [Edit: this one doesn't work, see comments below]: for a flat, but perhaps more contrived, example, I think one can take $\mathscr{X}:=B\mu_{3,\mathbb{Q}} \amalg B(\mathbb{Z}/3)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $X:=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})\amalg\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})$, where $\mathscr{X}\to X$ is the coarse moduli space map. Here $\mu_{3,\mathbb{Q}}$ is the nonconstant group scheme over $\mathbb{Q}$ defined as a covariant functor on $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras by $A\mapsto$ third roots of $1$ in $A$, and $(\mathbb{Z}/3)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the constant group scheme defined on $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras by $A\mapsto\mathbb{Z}/3$ (Edit: this is for connected $Spec(A)$, in general it's a *locally* constant group scheme, as by the way it has to be a locally constant sheaf of groups).
Now, I think the two basechanges along the two possible maps $\mathrm{Spec}(k)\to X$, $k$ algebraically closed, are both the gerbe $B\mu_{3,k}=B(\mathbb{Z}/3)_k$.

Comment: This seems to work. The fibres are $BG$, right? The morphism is also smooth, no?

Comment: Fibres are $BG$. It doesn't seem flat to me though. If $*:=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C})$, then $*\to BG$ is an étale atlas, in particular smooth hence flat; so if $f$ were flat it would be at every point of source, and the  the composition $*\to BG\to\mathbb{A}^1$ would be flat but it's not. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, that works (as in shows that the morphism is non-flat) even with G trivial; thank you for your help.  Imposing flatness or smoothness of the morphism I started with seems awkward, but my guess is that it might be possible for a "fiberwise" criterion to hold with these additional hypotheses.

Comment: I'm not sure whether your example in the "Added" works. The neutral gerbe $B(\mu_3)$  over $\mathbb Q$ is isomorphic to the gerbe $B(\mathbb Z/3)$, as they are both $\mathbb Z/3$-gerbes with a section (so neutral). So, I think that $\mathcal X$ is $B(\mathbb Z/3)_{X}$.

Comment: But the group schemes $\mu_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3$ themselves are not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$, right? On the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}$, the first has value the trivial group (1 is the only third root of unity in $\mathbb{Q}$), while the second has value $\mathbb{Z}/3$. Can taking $B(.)$ make them into isomorphic gerbes already over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Qfwfq You are right that $\mu_3$ are $\mathbb Z/3$ are non-isomorphic over $\mathbb Q$. Indeed, the group $\mu_3$ has no non-trivial sections over $\mathbb Q$. On the other hand, it is quite common for two neutral gerbes to be isomorphic even when the relevant group schemes are not. For a geometric example: consider the stack of smooth conics $B(PGL_2)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Let $X$ be a non-split smooth conic over $\mathbb Q$ with automorphism group $G$. Then $B(PGL_2)$ is isomorphic to $BG$, but $G$ is not isomorphic to $PGL_2$. (Here I write $PGL_2$ for what I should write $PGL_{2,\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: @Ariyan: interesting - can it even happen over $\mathbb{C}$? I mean, that $BG\cong BH$ for non isomorphic complex algebraic groups $G$ and $H$.

Comment: @Qfwfq I don't think so. As is explained in Lecture 3 of these notes http://pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~holmesdst/Vistoli_torsors.pdf it follows that the group scheme $H$ is an inner form of $G$. But all inner forms are trivial over $\mathbb C$ (i.e., isomorphic to $G$). (I think that should be right, although I didn't really check my last claim. Nonetheless it should follow from the fact that all $G$-torsors are trivial over Spec $\mathbb C$, as they have sections.) What happens in the example over $\mathbb Q$ is that there are non-trivial $PGL_{2,\mathbb Q}$-torsors (non-split smooth conics).

Comment: @Ariyan: yes, of course, all $G$-torsors over $\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{C}$ are trivial. I think I really wanted to ask this instead: working in the category of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes, if $S$ is a scheme and $G$ and $H$ non isomorphic group schemes over $S$, can it happen that $BG\cong BH$ (as stacks over $S$)? (here $BG:=[*/G/S]$ as per L.MB.'s book)

Comment: @Qfwfq That can certainly happen. Take $S$ to be the spectrum of a field (containing $\mathbb C$) such that there is a smooth conic $C$ over $S$ with no section. Let $G$ be the automorphism group scheme of $C$ over $S$. Then it follows that $BG = BPGL_{2,S}$, with $G$ not isomorphic to $PGL_{2,S}$. If you also want $S$ to be a finite type, then you will have to find a variety $S$ and a smooth conic with no section over $S$. This can be a bit more difficult (because of Tsen's theorem), but it should still be possible if $S$ is of dimension bigger than 1.

Comment: @Ariyan. Thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: Just for fun: Example of a conic over $\mathbb{C}(s,t)$ with no rational point: $sx^2 + ty^2 = z^2$.